# Countif function in excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, vba

```
Company  No of days   Closed
A           20          Yes
D           61          Yes
B           60          Yes
C            1          No
D            1          No
A            1          Yes
D            1          No
C            1          Yes
```

Suppose i have data like above on Column A,B,C
I want to count the number "A" in Closed = 'Yes' & No of days>5

I have tried the following and i'm not getting anything.

```
=IF(A:A="A",(IF(C:C="Yes",COUNTIF(B:B,">5"))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your table starts in `Range("A1")` you could try to use `=COUNTIFS` function:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A9,"A",B2:B9,">5",C2:C9,"Yes")
```

for the whole columns A:C:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"A",B:B,">5",C:C,"Yes")
```

Comment: Works absolutely great! Thanks @KazJaw

Comment: Incase i had another Column D with Yes1,Yes2,Yes3. Suppose now i want to pick "A" with only Yes1 & Yes2 & rest of the criteria as before than how would your formula change. Can you please let me know.

Comment: inside parenthesis you need to keep the following syntax `=COUNTIFS(range1, criteria1, range2, criteria2, ... and so on)`. So, you just need to add additional pair of `rangeX, criteriaX`.

Comment: Thanks,Got it. However if i want Yes1 & Yes2 to be included in one criteria for a range then how would it look like :)

Comment: Hmm, I think you need to do it in this way: `=COUNTIFS(..., "YES1") + COUNTIFS(..., "YES2")` which means that you need to add two `COUNTIFS` results

Comment: If you want to include all values beginning with "Yes" try using a "wildcard", i.e. `=COUNTIFS(A:A,"A",B:B,">5",C:C,"Yes*")` or for explicitly "Yes1" and "Yes2" try `=SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A,"A",B:B,">5",C:C,{"Yes1","Yes2"}))`

Comment: @barry This works great! Suppose there is a data column and I want to pull records only for the current week. What should I add to the above formula

Comment: Easiest way is to have start of week date in a cell, e.g. F2, then assuming dates in column D add 2 more criteria, `D:D, ">="&$F$2,D:D, "<"&$F$2+7` - if you want F2 to be automated use this formula in that cell assuming Monday is week start `=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),-3)`

Comment: @barry Thanks! I am getting a NUM error for =TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),-3), guess the formatting is creating an issue?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know where -3 came from it should be 3! `=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),3)`